# What is the --watch and --debug option in nest start

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I read following documentation described `nest` command.

https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/scripts

According to the document, following must be added to `package.json`

```
"build": "nest build",
"start": "nest start",
"start:dev": "nest start --watch",
"start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
```

What are the `--watch` and `--debug` options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, `--watch` means the terminal will stay open and watch for any file changes and then reload the server. `--debug` means it will log more messages to the console (e.g. info or warnings), which can be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 16):

According to the [nestjs start docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-start) the actual uses are as follows;

`--watch`

```
Run in watch mode (live-reload)
Alias -w
```

Source files which are saved with changes are automatically compiled without the need to manually run `npm run start` to trigger webpack compilation after every change.

For example, typescript files with changes (on save, or when using git) in `src` will be compiled to javascript files in `dist` (depending on your setup)

`--debug`

```
Run in debug mode (with --inspect flag)
Alias -d
```

The `--debug` flag [actually runs the node process](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) using the `--inspect` flag to allow native debugging using an IDE or otherwise. Once the node process is running, you can use an IDE to connect to to the node debug address and port (default 127.0.0.1:9229) and use breakpoints* to pause execution.

*However, do note that the above at present isn't *completely* accurate. IDEs usually need the `--inspect-brk` flag (for breakpoints) and it seems [there is still a problem](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/pull/607) with the nestjs implementation.

Some IDEs (for example VS Code) can get around this with an [auto-attach feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach) and it seems `--debug` is not even needed. Although very easy to set up, it is not as streamlined when developing multiple running node apps.